Duplicate Class Implementation in SQLite causing objc[XXXXX] Error in Xcode Project
I'm encountering an issue in my iOS project where I'm getting the following error messages in the console when I run my app:
objc[XXXXX]: Class _TtC6SQLite6Backup is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinkServices.framework/LinkServices (0x20263ad48) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/SobrietyHelper.app/SobrietyHelper (0xXXXXXXXX). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[XXXXX]: Class _TtC6SQLite10Connection is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinkServices.framework/LinkServices (0x20142f7a8) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/SobrietyHelper.app/SobrietyHelper (0xXXXXXXXX). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[XXXXX]: Class _TtC6SQLite9Statement is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinkServices.framework/LinkServices (0x20142f878) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/SobrietyHelper.app/SobrietyHelper (0xXXXXXXXX). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[XXXXX]: Class _TtC6SQLite13DateFunctions is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinkServices.framework/LinkServices (0x20263acb0) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/SobrietyHelper.app/SobrietyHelper (0xXXXXXXXX). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[XXXXX]: Class _TtC6SQLite12TableBuilder is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinkServices.framework/LinkServices (0x20263ab10) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/SobrietyHelper.app/SobrietyHelper (0xXXXXXXXX). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Additionally, I'm using Amplify and Core Data in my project, and I've set up my Core Data stack as follows:
import CoreData
import Amplify
import AWSDataStorePlugin

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext

        // Create sample data for preview
        let newGoal = Goal(context: viewContext)
        newGoal.goalDays = 30
        newGoal.startDate = Date()

        let newRecord = DrinkRecord(context: viewContext)
        newRecord.count = 3
        newRecord.date = Date()

        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "SobrietyHelper")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        
        // Amplify configuration
        configureAmplify()
    }

    private func configureAmplify() {
        do {
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSDataStorePlugin(modelRegistration: AmplifyModels()))
            try Amplify.configure()
            print("Amplify configured with DataStore plugin")
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred setting up Amplify: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

Steps I've Taken:
Clean Build: Performed clean and rebuilt the project.
Simulator Reset: Erased all content and settings in the simulator.
Checked for Duplicate Libraries: Verified in Link Binary With Libraries and found no duplicates.
Searched for SQLite in Project: Used find command and Xcode's search, but no explicit references to SQLite.swift.
Questions:
Is this duplicate class implementation a critical issue for my app?
How can I resolve this error to avoid potential runtime issues?
Are there any known issues with Amplify and Core Data integration that might cause this?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

This is a known Apple bug; there is nothing you can do to fix it. On the other hand, it is harmless since both versions are very likely the same. We hope that Apple will address it at some point.
